# How create a connection between more than 2 device without any server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sockets

all is in the question..
I would know how to create a connection between an iPad/iPhone(sender) and a lot of others devices iPad/iPhone (listeners). The chalenge is : I have to create this without using any intermediate server.
Each devices listeners should respond 'in live' to each sender message.
Any suggestion how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need multicast DNS (Apple calls it Bonjour). See http://developer.apple.com/opensource/ for the start of Apple's documentation, and see http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/ for a nice writeup.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Bonjour framework.  The devices will have to be on the same subnet, but you are able to connect them without the use of a server.  Apple provides some good sample code for the Bonjour framework.  I have not released an app using Bonjour, but I have done a few development/proof-of-concept apps with Bonjour.

Answer (score 0):

If all the devices are on the same LAN, you can just have them discover each other using broadcast or multicast UDP, and then (once they know each other's IP addresses) communicate with each other directly either via UDP or TCP.   (of course, the number of direct TCP connections required increases very quickly with the number of devices, so that will only scale to certain extent.  UDP could scale further, since it doesn't require a connection to be set up between every pair of devices).

The real problem is if (as is likely) the devices are at various places on the Internet, and some or all of them are behind NATs and firewalls.  In that case, about the only thing you can rely on is the devices' ability to make an outgoing TCP connection, in which case you almost require a server for them to connect to, because they won't be able to connect directly to each other in most cases (that NATs/firewalls will filter out the incoming TCP connection packets for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Peer-to-Peer connectivity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1) via Bluetooth (this is part of the GameKit API in iOS).

Comment: In fact, I was thinking about bluetooth but I think the distance range could be a problem =/ Even if the application should be use in the same room..

Comment: Hmmm.. in that case, all devices would have to be registered on the same network, so you might be able to achieve what you want using Bonjour, as @iPhone Guy and @Femi suggested. If you still prefer Bluetooth (and want to go wild :)), see if you could implement a solution where each device is able to maintain a list of "present" devices and route messages from origin to destination in a true P2P manner... Might be overkill over Bluetooth, though!!